# Insert new row and update relation key in another table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, stored-functions

I have these three tables for illustration purpose;

All products imported from various sources are added to this table.

```
desc data_import;
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| retailer | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| brand    | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title    | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

select * from data_import;
+----+----------+---------+--------------+
| id | retailer | brand   | title        |
+----+----------+---------+--------------+
|  1 | Amazon   | Samsung | Galaxy Alpha |
|  2 | Newegg   | Samsung | Galaxy Alpha |
+----+----------+---------+--------------+
```

This is table holds unique products for each retailer.

```
desc products;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

select * from products;
+----+--------------+
| id | title        |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Galaxy Alpha |
+----+--------------+
```

This is the relations table.

```
desc products_rels;
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| data_import_id | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| product_id     | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| retailer_id    | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| brand_id       | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | 0       |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

select * from products_rels;
+----+----------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| id | data_import_id | product_id | retailer_id | brand_id |
+----+----------------+------------+-------------+----------+
|  1 |              1 |          1 |           1 |        1 |
|  2 |              2 |          0 |           2 |        1 |
+----+----------------+------------+-------------+----------+
```

How can one add `Galaxy Alpha` for retailer `Newegg` to `products` and update the relation key in table `products_rels`?

Is that even possible, and how do I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)?

Comment: No, because I can't figure out a way to match `NEW.id` for `products` with `data_import.id`